# How to call ajax on every focus out in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Well i am developing a web application for marbal factory. Now i am facing an issue i have multiple rows of records where user can edit it simply i have five field of each records in shape of input what i want when user change value an ajax request should fire and update the data according to the row id i have done it but the problem is i have to rewrite the whole ajax code for different input fields i want something generic.

**here is my html**

```
<div class="l-row" data-value="<?=$row->id; ?>">
                <div class="l-col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Item</label>
                   <input type="text" name="item" id="item" value="<?=$row->name?>" class="form-control"  />
                  </div>
              </div>

                <div class="l-col-md-1">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Size</label>
                      <input type="text" name="size" id="size" value="<?=$row->size?>" class="form-control"  />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="l-col-md-1">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Type</label>
                   <input type="text" name="type" id="type" value="<?=$row->type?>" class="form-control"  />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="l-col-md-1">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Thickness</label>
                    <input type="text" name="thickness" id="thickness" value="<?=$row->thickness;?>" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="l-col-md-1">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Feet</label>
                    <input type="text" name="feet" id="feet" value="<?=$row->feet;?>" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="l-col-md-1">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">Sale</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sale" readonly="readonly" id="sale" value="<?=$row->sale;?>" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="l-col-md-2">
                   <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <label for="inputInfo1" class="control-label">S-Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" name="s_amount" readonly="readonly" id="s_amount" value="<?=$row->s_amount;?>" class="form-control">
                  </div>
                  </div>


                </div>
```

**Here is my jquery script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).on('focusout','#item', function() {
  $agents=$(this).closest('.l-row');
  var valu=$agents.attr('data-value');
  var item=$agents.find('#item').val();
  var size=$agents.find('#size').val();
  var type=$agents.find('#type').val();
  var thickness=$agents.find('#thickness').val();
  var feet=$agents.find('#feet').val();
  var sale=$agents.find('#sale').val();
  var s_amount=$agents.find('#s_amount').val();

  alert(item);
  var page_id="<?=$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url()?>record_edit',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+valu+'&page_id='+page_id,
    success:function(data)
    {
      //alert(data);
    }
  });   
 });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple. You can simply use `this`. :)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('.l-row input[type="text"]').on('focusout', function() {
  $agents=$(this).closest('.l-row');
  var valu=$agents.attr('data-value');
  var item=$(this).val(); // here, this will be the input element that just fired a focusout event.

  alert(item);
  var page_id="<?=$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url()?>record_edit',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+valu+'&page_id='+page_id,
    success:function(data)
    {
      //alert(data);
    }
  });   
 });
 </script>
```

This will attach `focusout` event handlers for all the inputs with `"type=text"` in ide the `div` with `class="l-row"`

Comment: you got it let me check this one

Comment: Why use focusout instead of blur on input field?

Comment: Best way to help yourself is to first read the `docs` :) http://api.jquery.com/focusout/

Comment: From the docs `The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus. This is distinct from the blur event in that it supports detecting the loss of focus on descendant elements (in other words, it supports event bubbling).`

Comment: Since we do not need `bubbling` in this case, it is semantically correct to use `focusout` instead of `blur`. The `blur` event will work anyway, but it is best to follow the ethos that are outlined by the framework to ensure forward/backward compatibility. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `class` instead of `id` in this types of scenario, since however you are getting your elements using `this`, the same code will work.

```
 $(document).on('focusout','.item', function() { //target with element class .item
  $agents=$(this).closest('.l-row');
  var valu=$agents.attr('data-value');
  var item=$agents.find('.item').val(); //target all input elements with classname
  var size=$agents.find('.size').val();
  var type=$agents.find('.type').val();
  var thickness=$agents.find('.thickness').val();
  var feet=$agents.find('.feet').val();
  var sale=$agents.find('.sale').val();
  var s_amount=$agents.find('.s_amount').val();

  alert(item);
  var page_id="<?=$page=basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>";
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?=base_url()?>record_edit',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'id='+valu+'&page_id='+page_id,
    success:function(data)
    {
      //alert(data);
    }
  });   
});
```

> **Add a property `class="whatever you have given to id"` to each
>   elements**

Rest every process remains same.

Comment: brother i have to again rewrite the whole code for every input field i just want to minimize the code

Comment: Anytime.. happy coding.. :) If there are no other inputs, other than what you are talking then without using `class` you can directly use `input[type="text"]` in the place of `.item`. But this is too bad practice. So better is using `class` approach.. :)

Comment: no in parent div i am using class and than iterating in its child element to get values of my demands thats why use closet() function but i appreciate your efforts you like megamind ty ;-)